# Multiple <options> inside of logical && operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a dependent select box that has different  listed depending on a parent select. I'm assuming that the code is failing because the options need to be wrapped inside of a container, but I'm not sure what container they can be wrapped in if I do not want to recreate the  for each state.

To be honest, I'm not even sure this is the best way to go about it. I'm still very new to React and JS in general. This company has locations in more than two states as well, so perhaps there is a better way to scale this? Thank you

My code so far:

```
<select
  className="select"
  name="selectCity"
  onChange={this.onCityChange}
>
  <option value="" defaultValue>Select a City</option>
  {
    this.state.state === 'california' && 
      <option value="los-angeles">Los Angeles</option> 
      <option value="san-diego">San Diego</option> 
  }
  {
    this.state.state === 'texas' && 
      <option value="austin">austin</option> 
      <option value="dallas">Dallas</option> 
  }
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, even if you could have multiple elements without a parent element, that's still less than optimal for many reasons.

It's better to have a proper data structure and loop through the data set. For example:

```js
const cities = {
  california: [
    { value: "los-angeles", name: "Los Angeles" },
    { value: "san-diego", name: "San Diego" }
  ],
  texas: [
    { value: "austin", name: "Austin" },
    { value: "dallas", name: "Dallas" }
  ]
  // and so on
};
```

```html
<select
  className="select"
  name="selectCity"
  onChange={this.onCityChange}
>
  <option value="" defaultValue>Select a City</option>
  {cities[this.state.state].map( city => <option value={city.value}>{city.name}</option> )}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks JJJ. This is the answer that I went with, though I did need to add a logical && operator inside of the JSX expression to account when the State selector is undefined:  this.cities[this.state.state] != undefined && (cities map expression)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to group elements together when you don't want a wrapping element in the DOM.

```
<select className="select" name="selectCity" onChange={this.onCityChange}>
  <option value="" defaultValue>
    Select a City
  </option>
  {this.state.state === "california" && (
    <React.Fragment>
      <option value="los-angeles">Los Angeles</option>
      <option value="san-diego">San Diego</option>
    </React.Fragment>
  )}
  {this.state.state === "texas" && (
    <React.Fragment>
      <option value="austin">austin</option>
      <option value="dallas">Dallas</option>
    </React.Fragment>
  )}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you could take here. Separation of concerns makes your code more readable and maintainable later. Not seeing the rest of your code, I'm not sure exactly how I would plug into your component. What do you think of something like

```
const cities = {
    'california': {
        'los-angeles': 'Los Angeles',
        'san-diego': 'San Diego',
    },
    'texas': {
        'austin': 'Austin',
        'dallas': 'Dallas',
    },
};

const getOptions = (state) => {
    const cities = Object.keys(cities[state]);
    return cities.map(city => <option value={city}>{cities[city]}</option>);
}

<select
    className="select"
    name="selectCity"
    onChange={this.onCityChange}
>
    <option value="" defaultValue>Select a City</option>
    {
        getOptions(this.state.state);
    }
</select>
```